XOpenDisplay failed when using pkexec to launch Avalonia application with elevated privileges
I'm trying to run an Avalonia application with elevated privileges using pkexec on a Linux system. The command I use is:
pkexec /home/depaula/MyApp/RedundancyServerIHM

However, I'm encountering the following error:

   Unhandled exception. System.Exception: XOpenDisplay failed
   at Avalonia.X11.AvaloniaX11Platform.Initialize(X11PlatformOptions options)
   at Avalonia.AvaloniaX11PlatformExtensions.<>c.<UseX11>b__0_0()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.SetupUnsafe()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.Setup()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.SetupWithLifetime(IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
   at                    Avalonia.ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetimeExtensions.StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(AppBuilder builder, String[] args)
   at RedundancyIHM.Avalonia.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\otavio.paula\Documents\\RedundancyServerIHM.Avalonia\Program.cs:line 12
   Aborted (core dumped)

Context:
The application is developed using the Avalonia framework and is intended to provide a graphical user interface.
When I attempt to run the application as a regular user, it works fine. However, running it with pkexec leads to the XOpenDisplay error, indicating that it cannot connect to the X11 server.
Is there a recommended way to run graphical applications with elevated privileges on Linux without encountering this error?
I used xhost +SI:localuser:root to grant access to the X11 server for the root user, but it did not resolve the issue.
This approach resulted in the same XOpenDisplay failed error.

Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

try to execute the application with sudo -E applicationName
this command will keep the current environment variables associated with graphics to run a Gui Application in linux desktop
